# nginx - file not found if index.php/filename

Tags: url, nginx, routes

Nginx is giving a 'file not found' error if i put another URL param after the index.php:

```
http://localhost/index.php/testfile.html
```

How can I make nginx not give this error and treat the '/testfile.html' as a parameter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the url you've given, it expects there to be a **folder** called `index.php`, but it seems that you want to, in a way, pass the testfile.html to the index.php file, which you can do via `GET` or `POST`.

[PHP Get](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

[PHP Post](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Essentially, if you do something like `http://localhost/index.php?file=testfile.html`, you can access that variable thorugh $_GET and include it (using PHP).

This is assuming you need to do this dynamically, if you just want to include that file all the time, then you can just use PHP's include capabilities.

Comment: Yes thats right I am trying to implement something like a Front Controller, so index.php is my controller and then the 'testfile.html' is a param. Is there no way i can do it with a slash '/' ?